# Does Intersystems Caché has "mid" function?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I would like to know if there is ["mid"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_mid.asp) function on Intersystems Caché Database. I'm trying to use it to solve a problem here, where I need to read a string of any size from the 8th character and I'm receiving the following error:

```
    Error: General error
    SQLState:  S1000
    ErrorCode: 0
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for $EXTRACT.

You can find documentation [here](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20122/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_d_extract).